# What does cryptocurrency mean for governments?

Tags: government, cryptocurrency

As far as I understand, governments & banks create money into existence. Governments, when run correctly, use it to build infrastructure, give grants and create jobs.

What if everybody begins to use a cryptocurrency therefore nullifying the value of the governments currency?

- How will governments spend when nobody wants their money?

Answer (score 2):

Government's tax citizens and businesses in their currency. Earnings (even earnings in cryptocurrencies) are taxable income.

Comment: This doesn't even begin to answer the question.  It's a complete non-sequitr.